# Error in groovy beans

Tags: spring, groovy

I have this .groovy file

```
@RestController
class SimpleBeanApp{

    @Autowired
    String text

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String index(){
        "You can do: ${text}!"
    }

    beans {
        text String, "-Spring Boot with Groovy beans-"
    }

}
```

When i run it I have

> file...beans.groovy: 12: unexpected token: beans @ line 12, column 2. beans

which is the `beans{`, I have tried adding an annotation `@Bean` before `beans` but it doesn't work.

Comment: what's `beans` supposed to do?  That's not valid Groovy afaik

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to inject a `String text` with the `@Autowired` annotation at the beginning of your controller class.

Spring searches beans with type `String` in its dependency injection scopes. The line that doesn't compile was supposed to provide that missing bean.

I'm not familiar with groovy, but it has to look something like this:

```
@Bean
String text() {
    return "-Spring Boot with Groovy beans-"
}
```

That's how you create a bean of type `String` and name `text`. It will be found by springs dependency injection framework and linked to the `@Autowired` field at the top of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

what mana sugests is 'Java' construct. It will work, but is not groovy-ish. 
Indeed, groovy SHOULD allow you to create beans in a more 'groovy' way; by providing a beans closure.

I was searching to solve the same issue myself today.
Turned out I had to find out by myself... So providing here my 2 cents.

That 'beans' definition is actually a method belonging to a [GroovyBeanDefinitionReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/groovy/GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.html)

So, you need to create one such class and invoke its 'beans' method providing it a closure will the beans definition, like in the example in the javadoc.
(I love groovy, but from time to time I feel like I need to understand what the code means in a C-programmer fashion to understand what I'm really doing... must be bound to ageing...)

Note you need to get hold of the application context.
One way I found (there could be better ways) is:

```
class SimpleBeanApp implements ApplicationContextAware {
    ...
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        def beanConfig = new GroovyBeanDefinitionReader(applicationContext)
        beanConfig.beans {
            text String, "-Spring Boot with Groovy beans-"
        }
    }
}
```

Or, you could also put your beans configuration in a separate groovy script to be loaded while configuring your spring application. Like:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run ([DemoApplication,new ClassPathResource('/DemoConfig.groovy')] as Object[], args)
}
```

And put within a DemoConfig.groovy file the beans configuration:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

beans {
    ...
}
```

Note that DemoConfig.groovy should be located in:
/src/main/resources/DemoConfig.groovy